# Still getting 2503 and 2502 errors after failed Installation and system restored

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions

An update/install of OpenOffice just failed on a Win7 machine because of `internal errors 2503 and 2502`.  During the install I selected a new folder for the files and **unchecked** the option to delete previous software versions.

After the install failed I restored the system (was prompted to restore to pre-installation attempt) however I can now no longer access the previously installed version, nor repair the installation, nor reinstall the old version, all on account of `internal 2503 and 2502 errors`.

On tomshardware.co.uk it is suggested that the problem is the security permissions on the `C:\windows\installer folder`.

Looking at the permissions, no check boxes were shown in the Allow/Deny columns.  Only two User Names are shown: `System`, and `Administrators`.  My instinct is to Allow full access to both, however I cannot afford to take any risks with this machine and when I try to apply the new permissions I get an warning message  saying that changing `permission settings on system folders . can result in unexpected access problems and reduce security`.

This is "probably" nothing to be concerned about but I can't afford to screwup so .... should I continue?  (If not how can I resolve the errors?)

EDIT

found the following (edited below) at https://helgeklein.com/blog/2012/08/windows-7-default-file-system-permissions-listing :-

- c:\Windows

  - SYSTEM             change   allow   no_inheritance
  - SYSTEM                full   allow
  - Administrators        change   allow   no_inheritance
  - Administrators        full   allow

I assume this entry means that the default or a default setting (?!) for sub-folders of c:\Windows is for both SYSTEM and administrators to be allowed full control.  Is this correct?

**EDIT 2**

Posted a specific question re Security Permissions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1293736/is-there-a-danger-in-changing-security-permission-for-win-7-windows-to-a-defau)