# Is there a danger in changing security permission for Win 7 \Windows to a "default" setting?

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions, file-permissions, security-warning

After a failed program install I can now no longer access the previously installed version, nor repair the installation, nor reinstall the old version.

I think the security permissions on the `C:\windows\installer folder` may have been reset somehow, as no check boxes are shown in the Allow/Deny columns.

The information on default settings I have found [here](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2012/08/windows-7-default-file-system-permissions-listing) are :-

- c:\Windows

  - SYSTEM             change   allow   no_inheritance
  - SYSTEM                full   allow
  - Administrators        change   allow   no_inheritance
  - Administrators        full   allow

There seem to be two default security settings for SYSTEM and administrator accounts on the c:\Windows folder and its sub-folders.  This confuses me.

One of these settings is for Full control, however, when I try to apply this a warning message states that: `changing permission settings on system folders can result in unexpected access problems and reduce security`.

Is this warning regarding `unexpected access problems` something to be concerned about i.e are the *"problems"* being warned of somehow *impossible* to forsee or are they merely the obvious:- that permissions are inherited so a cascade can only reduce permissions not extend them?  Can I safely continue to change the permissions as described?

Answer (score 2):

Do not change permissions on sensitive Windows folders.

If you think your Windows has a problem, the steps possible are :

- Run [chkdsk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872425.aspx)
- Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- In the worse case, perform
  [Repair Install of Windows 7 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html)

Comment: It's a Win7 machine.
I tried chkdsk and got an error "CHKDSK cannot continue in read-only mode".  So I'm investigating this.  Thanks.

Comment: `chkdsk /f` to fix.

Comment: Ran `chkdsk/r/f` from cmd window and it prompted to run from the next startup.  Took 2hrs to complete.  Found free space marked as allocated and fixed.  After that as task manager etc failed to work used revo-uninstaller to remove the installation (OpenOffice - deleted 4,779 registry entries and 3,908 leftover files after which a deep uninstall removed a further 79 reg.items and 159 files).  Tried to install again and FAILED with internal 2502 and 2503 errors.  Ran chkdsk and found the same errors had returned...  Ran MalwareBytes and F-Secure and no hits. Anyway appreciate your reply, Thanks.

Comment: You're in a bad shape. It seems like you will not escape my third point. But if it won't work  you will need to reset Windows. Be sure to have good backups before starting.

Comment: Hope not!  I've posted another question (https://superuser.com/questions/1293991/lost-ability-to-uninstall-programs-on-win7) as another chkdsk (from a restart again) reported no error but a setupapi.app.log created when Windows reloaded had what appear to be two unresolved errors.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you attempt to edit permissions in the Windows folder you will get the warning message you encountered. This is simply a good reminder that if you make a destructive change in this folder structure it can cause your system to become unusable.

That said, if you're careful to apply the new NTFS permissions correctly, everything will be fine.

As always, it's best to have a backup of your system before making changes of this sort.

Comment: Thanks.  Do those defaults Full for SYSTEM and admin sound correct?